# Format Database Query Results into a JSON Array and Read into Form

Tags: php, ajax, database, arrays, json

I currently have this code which reads the first field in a database record which is specified by the user ('myid' being a text field which accepts a number) and prints it in one of the fields of a front end form.

How do I make a JSON array of all of the fields in the database and then print them to the relevant form field? Thanks

Back-End Code

```
 $id = $_POST['id'];

 $query = "SELECT * FROM Customers WHERE ID = '" . mysql_real_escape_string($id) . '"';
 $result= mysql_query($query);

 if (mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) { 
      while($row = mysql_fetch_row($result)) {

         echo $row[1];
               }
         }

else { 
// no 
// print status message 
echo "No rows found!"; 
     }
```

Front-End Code

---

```
 jQuery(document).ready(function(){ 
 jQuery("input.myid").keyup(function(e){ 
 e.preventDefault(); 
 ajax_search(); 
          }); 
     });

 function ajax_search(){
 var search_val=jQuery("input.myid").val(); 
 jQuery.post("find.php", {id : search_val}, function(data){

 jQuery("input.fname").val(data);  

        }   
)}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use function json_encode() to convert an array into json format. And convert to array from json using function json_decode().

you have to just pass one parameter in function that is the array you want to encode or decode.

Comment: Yea I understand, but how do I then put each element from the array into a separate text field on the front end? Can you call each particular element from the array in some way?

Comment: yes you can access the data from json array using key values. As you are accessing the value from array. I  u didn't get it I ill tell you with example. If u want

Comment: A quick example would be great. I have my array, I'm just unsure as to how I can split it into separate variables.

Comment: [{"10-2":"20"},{"11-2":"15"},{"12-3":"17"},{"13-4":"10"},{"14-5":"12"},{"15-6":"5"}] This is a json array in which {"10-2":"20"} is one element, in which "10-2" is key and "20" is value. u can access in this way.... echo array_name["10-2"];

Answer (score 1):

```
header("HTTP/1.0 200 OK");
header('Content-type: text/json; charset=utf-8');
header("Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate");
header("Expires: Mon, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT");
header("Pragma: no-cache");
if (mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) 
{
    while($row = mysql_fetch_row($result)) {
        echo json_encode( $row );
    }
}
else 
{ 
    // no 
    // print status message 
    echo json_encode( "No rows found!" );
}
die();
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, this does reference every field in the record, however I want to print each field to a different text box.. How would this be done?

Comment: In JS code, parse JSON result as object like: `var pdata = jQuery.parseJSON(data);` and set correspondent field values:
`jQuery("input.fname").val(pdata.first_name); `, `jQuery("input.lname").val(pdata.last_name); `

Comment: In this piece of code.. var pdata = jQuery.parseJSON(data).. 'data' is undefined, is this supposed to be the name of the array?